# not able to get the output back from serial console using pyserial

Tags: python, pyserial

I can send my command over serial port and it runs fine. I want my out put back to main program on host so that I can print it there. But its not working.

```python
    def send_to_console(ser: serial.Serial, command: str, wait_time: float = 0.5):
        command_to_send = command + "\r"
        ser.write(command_to_send.encode('utf-8'))
        sleep(wait_time)
        print(ser.read(ser.inWaiting()).decode('utf-8'), end="")
    
    with serial.Serial("/dev/ttyUSB2", 460800, bytesize=8, timeout=1) as ser:
        print(f"Connecting to {ser.name}...")
        send_to_console(ser, "")
        send_to_console(ser, "ifconfig", wait_time=5)
        msg=ser.read(64)
        print(msg)
        print(f"Connection to {ser.name} closed.")
```

My output is below and there is no data there. what am I doing wrong?

```
Connecting to /dev/ttyUSB2...

b''

Connection to /dev/ttyUSB2 closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was fine.. I found the issue. I had opened the serial terminal using minicom. If I kill my already opened terminal before running the code, the output of  command is sent back to main program.